# Why Spring Security is not working in my Spring Boot project?

Tags: security, spring-security, spring-boot

MY QUESTION! WHY Once admin or users after login, they can not get on their dashboards. It updates the pages "/" or "/ home", but does not go
to UserDashboards or AdminDashboards?!
I am trying to configure Spring boot with Spring security and DB() for an application.
 I have login-form in my home.jsp. User can login or registred in my site in modal window.
 I will show you only a portion of home.jsp

```
<!-- Header -->
<li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"><spring:message code="nav.section.link5"/></a></li>
        <c:if test="${email == null}">
        <li><a href="" class="smoothScroll" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1"><spring:message code="nav.section.link6"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="smoothScroll" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-2"><spring:message code="nav.section.link9"/></a></li>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${email != null}">
          <li><a href="/dashboards" class="smoothScroll">${email}</a></li>
          <li><a href="/accountLogout" class="smoothScroll"><spring:message code="nav.section.link10"></spring:message></a> </li>
        </c:if>

<!-- modal login
================================================== -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active"><spring:message code="nav.section.link6"/></button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-2" data-dismiss="modal"><spring:message code="nav.section.link9"/></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div align="center">
          <ul class="sign-social-icon">
            <li><a href="/facebookLogin" class="fa fa-facebook wow fadeIn sign-facebook" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/twitterLogin" class="fa fa-twitter wow fadeIn sign-twitter" data-wow-delay="0.6s"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/linkedinLogin" class="fa fa-linkedin wow fadeIn sign-linkedin" data-wow-delay="0.9s"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/googleLogin" class="fa fa-google-plus wow fadeIn sign-google" data-wow-delay="1.2s"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="or">
          <p><spring:message code="modal.section.h3"/></p>
        </div >

        <form:form method="post" action="/userLogin" id="contact-formL" class="form-horizontal">

        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

          <div class="control-group controls">
            <input type="email" class="reg"  placeholder="<spring:message code="modal.section.h6"/>" name="email" id="emailL" value="${dto.email}">
          </div>
          <div class="control-group controls ">
            <input type="password" class="reg"  id="passwordL" placeholder="<spring:message code="modal.section.h7"/>" name="password"  value="${dto.password}" >
          </div>

          <div class="sign form-actions">
            <input role="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block" value="<spring:message code="nav.section.link6"/>">
          </div>

        </form:form>

        <%--<div class="fmp">--%>
          <%--<a><spring:message code="modal.section.h4"/></a>--%>
        <%--</div>--%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- modal registration
================================================== -->

<div class="modal" id="modal-2">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1" data-dismiss="modal" ><spring:message code="nav.section.link6"/></button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active"><spring:message code="nav.section.link9"/></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <div align="center">
          <ul class="sign-social-icon">
            <li><a href="/facebookLogin" class="fa fa-facebook wow fadeIn sign-facebook" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/twitterLogin" class="fa fa-twitter wow fadeIn sign-twitter" data-wow-delay="0.6s"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/linkedinLogin" class="fa fa-linkedin wow fadeIn sign-linkedin" data-wow-delay="0.9s"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/googleLogin" class="fa fa-google-plus wow fadeIn sign-google" data-wow-delay="1.2s"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="or">
          <p><spring:message code="modal.section.h3"/></p>
        </div>

        <form:form action="/saveUser" modelAttribute="dto" name="myForm" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="control-group controls">
                <input type="email" class="reg"  placeholder="<spring:message code="modal.section.h6"/>" name="email" id="email" value="${dto.email}">
            </div>
          <div class="control-group controls ">
            <input type="password" class="reg"  id="password" placeholder="<spring:message code="modal.section.h7"/>" name="password"  value="${dto.password}" >
          </div>
          <div class="control-group controls">
            <input type="password" class="reg" id="conf"  placeholder="<spring:message code="modal.section.h8"/>" name="conf">
          </div>
          <div class="sign form-actions">
            <input role="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block" value="<spring:message code="nav.section.link9"/>">
          </div>
        </form:form>

        <div class="policy">
          <spring:message code="modal.section.h5"/>        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my login method in HomeController.class:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/userLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateOne(@RequestParam(required = true) String email, @RequestParam(required = true) String password, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user = userService.getByEmail(email);
        System.out.println("проверка пароля и имейла с  БД");
        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            session.setAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
            System.out.println("ЛОГИНИТСЯ!!!");
            if (userService.getByEmail(email).getRole().equals(Role.USER)) {
                System.out.println("SALUT USER!!");
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
                return "redirect:/";
            } else if (userService.getByEmail(email).getRole().equals(Role.MODERATOR)) {
                System.out.println("SALUT MODERATOR!!");
                session.setAttribute("moderator", user);
                return "redirect:/";
            } else if (userService.getByEmail(email).getRole().equals(Role.ADMIN)) {
                System.out.println("SALUT ADMIN!!");
                session.setAttribute("admin", user);
                return "redirect:/";
            }

        }
        return "redirect:/loginProblems";

    }
```

The users and admin then has to open their dashboards(using click on button  `<li><a href="/dashboards" class="smoothScroll">${email}</a></li>` in HEADER).

This is my DashboardController.class:

```
@Controller
public class DashboardsConroller {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    UserDataService userDataService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboards", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String selectDashboard(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("method selectDashboard!!");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user = userService.getByEmail((String) session.getAttribute("email"));
        System.out.println("СМОТРИ СЮДА = " + user);
        if (userService.getByEmail(user.getEmail()).getRole().equals(Role.USER)) {
            System.out.println("USER want to open dashboard!!");
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/userDash";
        } else if (userService.getByEmail(user.getEmail()).getRole().equals(Role.MODERATOR)) {
            System.out.println("Moderator want to open dashboard!!");
            session.setAttribute("moderator", user);
            return "redirect:/moderatorDash";
        } else if (userService.getByEmail(user.getEmail()).getRole().equals(Role.ADMIN)) {
            System.out.println("ADMIN want to open dashboard!!");
            session.setAttribute("admin", user);
            return "redirect:/adminDash";
        } else {
            System.out.println("LAST ELSE IS WORKING");
            return "redirect:/home";
        }

    }

}
```

This is my showAdminDashboard() method in AdminDashController.class:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/adminDash", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showAdminDashboard(@ModelAttribute("myUserData") UserData myUserData,
                                           @RequestParam(required = false) String firstName,
                                           @RequestParam(required = false) String secondName,
                                           HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {

        ...

    }
```

This is my showUserDashboard() method in UserDashController.class:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userDash", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showUserDashboard(@ModelAttribute("myUserData") UserData myUserData,
                                          @RequestParam(required = false) String firstName,
                                          @RequestParam(required = false) String secondName,
                                          HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        ...

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

This is my SecurityConfig.class :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/userLogin", "/dashboards", "/saveUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/adminDash").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/userDash").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/loginProblems")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/accountLogout"));

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

> WHY Once admin or users after login, they can not get on their dashboards.

It happens because user wasn't authenticated properly, in fact for a Spring Security, user is still not authenticated.

When you're using Spring Security, it should authenticate users (by finding user in the database, comparing passwords, assigning roles and so on). But you're trying to authenticate users by your own code (in `/userLogin`).

Comment: Yes you are right. But, I tried to remove a method /userLogin and create a role in memory , like this "    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }"

Comment: So far, for testing I use the admin user and not from the database. Still does not work ... Please tell me if I have a modal window for login and registration (/home or /), what should I write in the parameter .loginPage("/") or .loginPage("/home") or .loginPage("home.jsp") or .loginPage("/userLogin") in security config?

Comment: I suggest to start from reading documentation for the `loginPage` parameter at least: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage-java.lang.String- There you can find the requirements for a working authentication. Also I suggest to read an example of configuring Spring Security (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/guides/html5/) and try to apply it. When it starts working, then add some improvements (like users from the in-memory database).